# IE Overflow Scroll

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How do I remove the scrollbars but allow scrolling in internet explorer? It looks fine in FireFox/Chrome/Safari but it looks absolutely terrible in IE and is basically un-useable.

Here is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
table
{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th, td
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top:0px;
}
</style>
```

And here's a screenshot of my table in IE9-11 (they all look the same):

[image: hideous ie table]

It's so hideous...

Here is a fiddle with the code http://jsfiddle.net/EZM6x/

Comment: Link up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your html.

Comment: The table is 100% dynamic from a database, I cannot make a fiddle to accurately represent it.

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:auto`?

Comment: Same result, doesn't hide the scrollbars. I wouldn't have an issue if the scrollbars weren't so thick and persistent (if they vanished like Chrome it'd be fine..)

Comment: HTML code can be obtained for a fiddle with Firebug: go to HTML tab, hover the html opening tag and right click to choose Copy HTML. Paste  in a fiddle the least example of code reproducing the problem...

Comment: Posted the fiddle, it's like 9000 lines of HTML but it rendered for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the version of IE that it works in, and use this.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=//put version here">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This kind of worked for IE, but it ruined it for Chrome

Comment: When CSS doesnt work in all browsers it sucks, been there. Chris Coyier wrote this and it helps, but be very very careful not to get hung up on hacks to fix everything. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

I would totally disable the scrollbar, and add a jquery event and use the `animate` or `scrollTop` function to achieve the results.

Or you can use a scrollbar plugin like tinyscrollbar and set the scrollbar's CSS to `display:none`

If you can not use jquery, you can still align the scrollable areas above each other to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: I'd rather keep this CSS, that's why I didn't tag jQuery.

Comment: Then I suggest you to align the divs above each other to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: <!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->  For IE only